# Make pdb work with docker

Tags: docker, pdb

I am trying to get **pdb** working with **docker**

We have just started using docker in development. I run python scripts inside docker

I can attach to a docker container:

```
 docker exec  -ti 6e2355917804  /bin/bash
```

I can tail the output

```
 docker attach 6e2355917804
```

[I've read this](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/359) but I'm not using fig.

I can see the code hit the breakpoint but I can't interact with PDB.

Docker version 1.7.1,

Comment: Have a look at  https://hub.docker.com/r/stevemock/docker-pdb2pdbqt/~/dockerfile/

Comment: None of the solutions here worked for me. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58540510/8285811) using `remote-pdb` did however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't using the -i flag when launching my original docker container. 
Make sure to use

```
docker run -it <job>
```

Answer (score 5):

In case you are using docker compose, you need to do the following.

Step 1. Add the following in your yml file

```
stdin_open: true
tty: true
```

This will enable interactive mode and will attach stdin. This is equivalent for -it mode.

Step 2.

```
docker attach <generated_instance_id>
```

You'll now get the pdb shell