# Unable to debug or use pdb in Django: bdb.BdbQuit

Tags: python, django, debugging, python-3.7, django-2.2

I'm using Django `(2, 2, 4, 'final', 0)` within a docker, but I'm able to bash inside to open or execute whatever is required. But I can't debug. ([How to debug in Django, the good way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118183/how-to-debug-in-django-the-good-way) states some methods, none work for me)

Within my `views.py` I'm having various functions, for instance this here.

```
def visGraph(request):
    showgraph = 'Graphen'
    selectDB = request.GET.get('selectDB', '')
    __import__("pdb").set_trace()
    title += " <i>"+showgraph+"</i> ("+selectDB+")"
```

It works fine until I fill in the pdb, adding the debugger makes my app crash immediately:

```
> /code/DjangoGraphen/views.py(74)visGraph()
-> title += " <i>"+showgraph+"</i> ("+selectDB+")"
(Pdb) 
Internal Server Error: /DjangoGraphen/visGraph
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "./DjangoGraphen/views.py", line 74, in visGraph
    title += " <i>"+showgraph+"</i> ("+selectDB+")"
  File "./DjangoGraphen/views.py", line 74, in visGraph
    title += " <i>"+showgraph+"</i> ("+selectDB+")"
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/bdb.py", line 88, in trace_dispatch
    return self.dispatch_line(frame)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/bdb.py", line 113, in dispatch_line
    if self.quitting: raise BdbQuit
bdb.BdbQuit
ERROR:django.request:Internal Server Error: /DjangoGraphen/visGraph
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "./DjangoGraphen/views.py", line 74, in visGraph
    title += " <i>"+showgraph+"</i> ("+selectDB+")"
  File "./DjangoGraphen/views.py", line 74, in visGraph
    title += " <i>"+showgraph+"</i> ("+selectDB+")"
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/bdb.py", line 88, in trace_dispatch
    return self.dispatch_line(frame)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/bdb.py", line 113, in dispatch_line
    if self.quitting: raise BdbQuit
bdb.BdbQuit
[21/Oct/2019 17:47:14] "GET /DjangoGraphen/visGraph?selectDB=Test&showgraph=graph HTTP/1.1" 500 88178
```

It doesn't matter very much if I'm using `__import__("pdb").set_trace()` or `breakpoint()` - both return the same result.
In my settings.py I have so far `DEBUG = True`, setting it to `False` doesn't change anything.

I'm viewing the logs within my command line using:

```
docker logs django_web_1 -f
```

I assume for the pdb I require an active shell rather than just a log-viewer, but I can't figure out what to change or how to do that.
But tried already what's given here as an answer: [Interactive shell in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42443006/interactive-shell-in-django)
But it just opens a Python-Shell.

Comment: total guess, but try uninstalling bdp. maybe the terminal portion of it conflicts somehow, idk.

Comment: pdb works fine in any other python code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is actually rather easy. The problem is the docker. The solution is stated here and works:
https://medium.com/@vladyslav.krylasov/how-to-use-pdb-inside-a-docker-container-eeb230de4d11

Add this to your docker-compose.yml:

```
 ports:
      - "4444:4444"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

Install the `remote-pdb` and use instead of your default pdb command:

```
__import__("remote_pdb").set_trace(host='0.0.0.0', port=4444)
```

Log into your docker and telnet into the pdb session:

```
telnet 0.0.0.0 4444
```

Answer (score 6):

If you know you are going to end up in the debugger you can use `run` instead of `up`.

```sh
$ docker-compose run --rm --service-ports django_web
```

The problem is that `up` assumes it will run multiple services, even when you tell it to only run one, so it will wrap them for you. That's also why it prepends the output with the service name:

```sh
web_1  | Some output
db_1   | Some db logs
```

The `run` command [doesn't do this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/faq/#whats-the-difference-between-up-run-and-start) and so you can have a shell and a debugger without problems or remote_pdb workarounds.

NOTE: when using `run`, you have to [configure the dependencies](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on) because not everything is automatically started otherwise.

Comment: Can't even start it that way: `ERROR: No such service: django_web`, just using it in the folder where I'd usually just use `docker-compose up` makes me get a `Run a one-off command on a service.
` with some suggestions...

Comment: The first part suggests you have a different name in your `docker-compose.yml` for this particular service (or you're not running it in the project folder?).

The second part suggests you don't have a command specified for the service? Something like `command: ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0:8080"]` under the service you have for django in your `docker-compose.yml`.

If you want you can indeed specify custom one-off commands, like so:
`docker-compose run --rm --service-ports django_web my_custom_command`, which then overrides the default command from your `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: It's solved around two months ago. See my own answer

Comment: Yeah I've read your answer (I even referenced it in my original answer), but unless you have no control over how docker containers are started, I would advise to not install extra dependencies and just use what docker gives you, because it does work if you call docker-compose correctly.

Comment: @AllardStijnman I tried your method and many, many others which essentially referenced the same thing, but OP's answer is the only one that's worked for me.

Comment: I just want to confirm that this method does work. Not only that, but I believe this is the better answer since it doesn't rely on installing additional packages to your container.