# Pycharm debugging does not stop at breakpoints when starting Django server on docker-compose

Tags: django, debugging, docker-compose, pycharm

I have a Django project that I can perfectly debug when ran on my machine through the CLI, however when I moved the logic into Docker & docker-compose, even though it runs without any issu I can no longer debug it, i.e. it does not stop at breakpoints, even though I can see through the debugger console that Pydevd receives commands related to addition / deletion of breakpoints:

```bash
/usr/local/bin/python3 /opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiprocess --client host.docker.internal --port 55583 --file /opt/project/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 
Container project-api-db-1  Running
Container project-api-project-api-1  Recreate
Container project-api-project-api-1  Recreated
Attaching to project-api-project-api-1
project-api-project-api-1  | Executing PyCharm's `sitecustomize`
project-api-project-api-1  | User doesn't have a custom `sitecustomize`
project-api-project-api-1  | Custom matplotlib backend was set for SciView
project-api-project-api-1  | Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
project-api-project-api-1  | make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
project-api-project-api-1  | to python to disable frozen modules.
project-api-project-api-1  | Note: Debugging will proceed.
project-api-project-api-1  | Unable to load jupyter_debug plugin
project-api-project-api-1  | Executing file /opt/project/manage.py
project-api-project-api-1  | arguments: ['/opt/project/manage.py', 'runserver', '0.0.0.0:8000']
project-api-project-api-1  | PYDEVD_FILTER_LIBRARIES False
project-api-project-api-1  | 
project-api-project-api-1  | ('Connecting to ', 'host.docker.internal', ':', '55583')
project-api-project-api-1  | ('Connected.',)
project-api-project-api-1  | debugger: received >>501   1   0.1 UNIX
project-api-project-api-1  | <<
project-api-project-api-1  | Received command: CMD_VERSION 501  1   0.1 UNIX
Connected to pydev debugger (build 231.9225.15)
project-api-project-api-1  | 
project-api-project-api-1  | sending cmd -->          CMD_VERSION @@BUILD_NUMBER@@
project-api-project-api-1  | debugger: received >>111   3   python-line /opt/project/screenshots/schemas/screenshot.py  37  mutate  THREAD  None    None
project-api-project-api-1  | 101    9   
project-api-project-api-1  | 146    11  SHOW_RETURN_VALUES  0
project-api-project-api-1  | 111    5   python-line /opt/project/screenshots/views.py   5   index   THREAD  None    None
project-api-project-api-1  | 111    7   python-line /opt/project/screenshots/schemas/screenshot.py  43  mutate  THREAD  None    None
project-api-project-api-1  | <<
project-api-project-api-1  | Received command: CMD_SET_BREAK 111    3   python-line /opt/project/screenshots/schemas/screenshot.py  37  mutate  THREAD  None    None
project-api-project-api-1  | 
project-api-project-api-1  | Added breakpoint:/opt/project/screenshots/schemas/screenshot.py - line:37 - func_name:b'mutate'
project-api-project-api-1  | 
project-api-project-api-1  | Received command: CMD_RUN 101  9   
project-api-project-api-1  | 
project-api-project-api-1  | Received command: CMD_SHOW_RETURN_VALUES 146   11  SHOW_RETURN_VALUES  0
project-api-project-api-1  | 
project-api-project-api-1  | Show return values: False
project-api-project-api-1  | 
project-api-project-api-1  | Received command: CMD_SET_BREAK 111    5   python-line /opt/project/screenshots/views.py   5   index   THREAD  None    None
project-api-project-api-1  | 
project-api-project-api-1  | Added breakpoint:/opt/project/screenshots/views.py - line:5 - func_name:b'index'
project-api-project-api-1  | 
project-api-project-api-1  | Received command: CMD_SET_BREAK 111    7   python-line /opt/project/screenshots/schemas/screenshot.py  43  mutate  THREAD  None    None
project-api-project-api-1  | 
project-api-project-api-1  | Added breakpoint:/opt/project/screenshots/schemas/screenshot.py - line:43 - func_name:b'mutate'
project-api-project-api-1  | 
project-api-project-api-1  | sending cmd -->    CMD_THREAD_CREATE <xml><thread name="MainThread" id="pid_1_id_281473140200016" /></xml>
project-api-project-api-1  | IDE_PROJECT_ROOTS ['/opt/project']
project-api-project-api-1  | 
project-api-project-api-1  | LIBRARY_ROOTS ['/Users/user/Library/Caches/JetBrains/PyCharm2023.1/remote_sources/-2013456723/-853142961', '/Users/user/Library/Caches/JetBrains/PyCharm2023.1/remote_sources/-2013456723/78907351', '/Users/user/Library/Caches/JetBrains/PyCharm2023.1/remote_sources/-2013456723/-727148301', '/Users/user/Library/Caches/JetBrains/PyCharm2023.1/python_stubs/1437855905', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/python-skeletons', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stdlib', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/gdb', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/six', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/boto', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/mock', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/pytz', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/toml', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/tqdm', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/annoy', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/babel', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/emoji', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/first', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/fpdf2', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/ldap3', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/polib', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/redis', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/regex', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/retry', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/ujson', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/bleach', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/caldav', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/docopt', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/hdbcli', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/invoke', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/passpy', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/Pillow', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/psutil', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/pycurl', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/pynput', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/pysftp', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/PyYAML', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/stripe', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/xxhash', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/zxcvbn', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/appdirs', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/certifi', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/chardet', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/chevron', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/passlib', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/pyaudio', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/PyMySQL', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/pyvmomi', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/slumber', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/tzlocal', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/urllib3', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/vobject', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/aiofiles', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/colorama', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/croniter', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/docutils', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/html5lib', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/httplib2', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/jmespath', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/Markdown', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/oauthlib', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/openpyxl', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/paramiko', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/psycopg2', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/pyflakes', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/Pygments', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/requests', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/selenium', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/tabulate', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/toposort', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/waitress', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/braintree', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/decorator', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/freezegun', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/playsound', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/pyOpenSSL', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/pyRFC3339', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/termcolor', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/ttkthemes', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/typed-ast', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/xmltodict', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/cachetools', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/commonmark', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/dateparser', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/Deprecated', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/Flask-Cors', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/jsonschema', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/pyfarmhash', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/Send2Trash', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/setuptools', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/simplejson', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/SQLAlchemy', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/contextvars', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/entrypoints', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/flake8-2020', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/JACK-Client', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/mysqlclient', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/opentracing', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/pep8-naming', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/prettytable', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/python-jose', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/python-nmap', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/stdlib-list', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/atomicwrites', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/aws-xray-sdk', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/cryptography', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/editdistance', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/parsimonious', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/whatthepatch', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/click-spinner', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/DateTimeRange', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/humanfriendly', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/python-gflags', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/beautifulsoup4', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/flake8-bugbear', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/python-slugify', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/singledispatch', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/dj-database-url', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/flake8-builtins', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/flake8-simplify', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/mypy-extensions', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/python-dateutil', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/Flask-SQLAlchemy', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/flake8-docstrings', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/flake8-plugin-utils', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/pytest-lazy-fixture', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/flake8-rst-docstrings', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/flake8-typing-imports', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/typeshed/stubs/backports.ssl_match_hostname']
project-api-project-api-1  | 
project-api-project-api-1  | Executing PyCharm's `sitecustomize`
project-api-project-api-1  | User doesn't have a custom `sitecustomize`
project-api-project-api-1  | Custom matplotlib backend was set for SciView
project-api-project-api-1  | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
project-api-project-api-1  | Performing system checks...
project-api-project-api-1  | 
project-api-project-api-1  | System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
project-api-project-api-1  | July 14, 2023 - 18:52:12
project-api-project-api-1  | Django version 4.2.3, using settings 'project_api.settings'
project-api-project-api-1  | Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
project-api-project-api-1  | Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
project-api-project-api-1  | 
project-api-project-api-1  | [14/Jul/2023 18:52:15] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 13
project-api-project-api-1  | [14/Jul/2023 18:52:19] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 13
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:13.11-bullseye
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - database.env
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  skreenshottr-api:
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - db

networks:
  backend:
    name: backend
    external: true

volumes:
  postgres_data:
    driver: local
```

Here are my Python Interpreter configuration as well as my Django Server Run/Debug config:
[image: Python Interpreter configuration] [image: Django Server Run/Debug config]

The code works like a charm, but never stops at breakpoints, even though when manually starting Django without using Docker, it stops at the breakpoints. Restarting PyCharm/Computer, updating PyCharm, deleting .idea folder or invalidating cache didn't work either.

EDIT:

- PyCharm version: 2023.1.4
- Pro Python version: 3.11.4
- Docker version: 20.10.23

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `python-alpine` as a base image, try using python base image (e.g `FROM python:3.11`). Alpine image is so minimal that might not include dependencies for remote debugger that pycharm needs. Changing the base image worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Docker recreates everything in its containers so you will not be able to access it with your standard debugging tools. It is possible to use `pdb` however to interactively debug. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58540510/8285811).